# creating channel with 3 organizations failure

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I tried to  create 3 organizations in a channel,which already coded for two organizations so I have done some editings in docker-compose-e2e-template,crypto-config, docker-compose-cli,configtx, docker-compose-couch and in byfn.sh files . I had followed the Build your first network in hyperledger-fabric readthedocs the terminal runs until the./byfn.sh generate command but it is not creating channel in `./byfn.sh up`.
I have got the Error：

```
2018-10-30 04:30:32.370 UTC [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, folder
"/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" does not exist
```

Comment: It's hard to read your question, please edit it and state: 1) what you want to do, 2) what you've tried so far, 3) what problems you're running into.

Answer (score 0):

this tutorial how to setup your first step https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/build_network.html
after that this step by step how to add new ORG 
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/channel_update_tutorial.html#

If this not working with you please share more details about your ENV

Comment: this one i have done I am trying to create a channel with three organisations rather than adding organisation to a channel

Comment: So your Env is up and running ? and you are trying to create new Channel to include all 3 Orgs., also this tutorial already add the new Org3 to the same existing channel (mychannel)

Comment: But I have removed everything and started to edit the yaml files and then I have followed build your first network.